# How center elements but display them on top of each other

Tags: css

Is there a way to center the childs of an elements horizontal and vertical but display all of them on top of each other, as if they had `position: absolute`. But without setting the style for each child independently.

```
<div style="widht: 100: height: 100">
  <div style="widht: 80: height: 80">
  <div style="widht: 60: height: 60">
  <div style="widht: 40: height: 40">
  <div style="widht: 20: height: 20">
</div>
```

Result should like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post you code?

Comment: **"as if they had position: absolute"**...the answer is in the question...No!?

Comment: Do the elements all have fixed sizes? @Paulie_D if the elements are nested you don't need position absolute I guess

Comment: They have a fixed size but cant be nested.

Comment: I would say that it's a shipload of divs just to create a 'design element' that could be better served by an image or SVG.

Comment: This is just a simplified example. In the end I'm looking for a way to combine the core elements of this library: http://eskimoblood.github.io/jim-knopf/ without calculating there position.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't nest your divs you can use `position:absolute;` and top/left values to position each div :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7MRLy/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="wrap" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div class="one" style="width: 80px; height: 80px;"></div>
    <div class="two" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"></div>
    <div class="three" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"></div>
    <div class="four" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    background:#38E1BA;
    border:5px solid #000;
}
.one{
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
.two{
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
}
.three{
    top:25px;
    left:25px;
}
.four{
    top:35px;
    left:35px;
}
```

Comment: nice. it would also be possible to use the adjacent sibling selector for this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7MRLy/2/ this could also be done with % based inner `divs`. although the border may cause issue with alignment, you could also use twice as many `divs` to create faux borders and correct that.

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to do this in the **current html format** as far as i know is with absolute or relative positioning...

if you can change format you can either use **multiple background images on the same element** or **nest the elements**..

Comment: well you could although it wouldn't be the best solution use relative positionning and position each div. So abbsolute positionning isn't the only way to go.

Comment: @web-tiki you could technically position relative adjacent divs on top of each other with negative positioning, true.. but why do that?! :)

Comment: That is what I stated in my previous comment, it is not the best way but I wanted to point out that " There is no way to do this without absolute position..." is not true.